# How can I mimic this pixelated screen and slightly blurred effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, gradient, pixelation

The top image looks great with header text in the center but with my two tries the text gets jumbled into the background so I tried lightening it so the text would pop more. This is being use for a banner on a website. There's also an issue with photographing the screen and getting weird lines and/or a purple-ish arc show up in the picture. I think it's the *Moire effect*. Not sure how to get rid of it.

I started with photographing my screen close up to get the pixels but I can't quite get it too like this:

[image: Image example]

Mine looks like this:

[image: My image]
[image: My second image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a screen shot - don't photograph (this will avoid screen patterns).
2. Manipulate screenshot in image editing program of your choice (which should support layers, masking, and provide tools for creating blur effects).
3. Create tilted/perspective look by turning your screenshot into its own layer then adjusting the bounding box of that layer to create the tilt/perspective look.
4. Next apply a vignette effect (gradient of a lightly transparent white to fully transparent) layer over your screenshot layer.
5. Then add a blur filter (masked appropriately so you don't blur everything) to create the blurring at the edges. The blur effect could be applied directly to the vignette layer, or, even better, be an adjustment layer over all the layers.